# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array" via 32bit ODBC data source?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, dts, progress-db

I get an "Index was outside the bounds of the array." error when I do the following.

1) I launch the Import and Export Data Wizard (32 bit).

2) Data source: .Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc.

3) I provide a connection string and DSN for a 32 bit Progress OpenEdge 10.2A ODBC driver that I've set up.

4) I set up a flat file destination.

5) When I click "Next" I get the following error:

### TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Column information for the source and the destination data could not be retrieved, or the data types of source columns were not mapped correctly to those available on the destination provider.

"VISION"."PUB"."tlrtran" -> C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\flat-file.txt:

```
   - Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I received this same error when trying to import data into SQL from a DNS for 32 bit ProvideX ODBC driver for Sage MAS90 software. I got around it by creating the destination table first and then using the option to write a query instead of copy data from one or more tables or view.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when tried to import from Sybase. It works when change to use the query instead to copy table.