# Exporting data in CSV file format from SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, export, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a data table from SQL Server to a `.CSV` file format, but could not proceed any further after this warning. And I don't know how to fix this, and I need to go further in my job.

[image: Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array" via 32bit ODBC data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224336/sql-server-import-and-export-wizard-error-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export query result to .csv file in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169220/export-query-result-to-csv-file-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a query to retrieve the data you want to export
Right click on the result and save as csv file. see image bellow
[image]